# How I get JavaScript localStorage value after redirect to another page in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I save localStorage value successfully but after redirecting to another page I won't get localStorage value.

My signup.vue file:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <form ref="uformref" id="sform">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
      <p id="emailerror"></p>
      <label for="email">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
      <p id="passworderror"></p>
      <label for="email">Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" />
      <p id="password2error"></p>

      <input
        class="mysubmit"
        type="submit"
        @click.prevent="signup"
        value="Submit"
      />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
// This script successfully save localstorage value

export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  methods: {
    async signup() {
      // serialize form data into json
      let form = document.querySelector("#sform");
      var obj = {};
      var elements = form.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea");
      //  console.log(elements);
      //  console.log(typeof(elements));
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var name = element.name;
        var value = element.value;
        if (name) {
          obj[name] = value;
        }
        var jj = JSON.stringify(obj);
      }

      await this.$axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/signup/", jj)
        .then((response) => {
          // console.log(response.data)
          if (response.data.result === "error") {
            document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML =
              response.data.response.email !== undefined
                ? response.data.response.email
                : "";
            document.getElementById("passworderror").innerHTML =
              response.data.response.password !== undefined
                ? response.data.response.password
                : "";
            document.getElementById("password2error").innerHTML =
              response.data.response.password2 !== undefined
                ? response.data.response.password2
                : "";
          } else if (response.data.result === "success") {
            localStorage.setItem("response", response.data.response);

            // let access_token = response.data.refresh
            // let refresh_token = response.data.access
            // this.$auth.setUserToken(access_token, refresh_token)
            this.$router.push("/signin/");
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // error.response.status Check status code
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

.mysubmit {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
p {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

My signin.vue file:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <form enctype=“multipart/form-data” ref="uformref">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
      <p id="emailerror"></p>
      <label for="email">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
      <p id="passworderror"></p>

      <input class="ssubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <p id="dkey"></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

.ssubmit {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
// This script is not displaying localstorage value

export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  methods: {
    async displaykey() {
      document.getElementById("dkey").innerHTML =
        localStorage.getItem("response");
      console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("response")));
    },

    created: function () {
      this.displaykey();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

My script is not displaying localStorage value after redirect to another page. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does it redirect to the same domain?

Comment: No, It redirect to the another domain

Comment: That's not how localstorage works, localstorage is bound to a domain.

Comment: No, It Doesn't my answer

Comment: A couple of issues: **1)** `jquery` is not mentioned/used anywhere in your code, therefore `jquery` tag is unnecessary; **2)** the quotes used around the `enctype` attribute of `<form>` are not normal quotes (`"`). They are `“` and `”`. They might not be parsed correctly by browsers, most likely resulting in invalid markup.

Comment: @PritpalSingh As you are redirecting to the another page. One possible solution is to pass localstorage data via url param and when you redirect to different url fetch those data from url and store it in localstorage again.